# How do I access data from my Rails query object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed this (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/active-record-eager-loading-with-query-objects-and-decorators) tutorial to build my query object, but how do I access my store data from the result???

I get following object with I go result = StoreWithRecentDeals.new(store: Store.all)

Query Object https://gist.github.com/jianbo/4125f3203005358e99f5

then I want to get my stores and deals data out of this object, when I go result.stores I get
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

This is my code

```
class StoreWithRecentDeals
    def initialize(stores:)
      @stores = stores.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
      @deal_cache = build_deal_cache
    end

    def stores
      @stores.map { |store| StoreWithLatestDeals.new(store, @deal_cache) }
    end

    private

    def build_deal_cache
      deals.group_by(&:store_id)
    end

    def deals
      Deal.
        select("*").
        from(Arel.sql("(#{ranked_deals_query}) AS ranked_deals")).
        where("deal_rank <= 3")
    end

    def ranked_deals_query
      Deal.where(store_id: @stores.map(&:id)).select(<<-SQL).to_sql
        deals.*,
        dense_rank() OVER (
          PARTITION BY deals.store_id
          ORDER BY deals.created_at DESC
        ) AS deal_rank
      SQL
    end
  end

  class StoreWithLatestDeals < SimpleDelegator
    def initialize(store, deals_by_store_id)
      super(store)
      @deals_by_store_id = deals_by_store_id
    end

    def latest_deals
      @deals_by_store_id[id] || []
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

What i guess your problem is, You have in class `StoreWithRecentDeals` : `stores` as instance variable name as well as method name.

I will suggest to give some other name to your method:

```
def fetch_stores
  @stores.map { |store| StoreWithLatestDeals.new(store, @deal_cache) }
end
```